# RPi 4 + Selenium + Firefox + Geckodriver: errors when running

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run selenium **4.1.0** through firefox on my raspberry pi 4 running raspbian/raspiOS (can't use chromium. been there tried that.).

I am using geckodriver **0.23.0** (latest that has arm7 download). My firefox version is **78.15.0esr** (from **about:support**), which according to [this](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html) should be supported by that driver version, I think.

In case it means anything, I installed firefox through `sudo apt install firefox-esr`.

My (relevant) python3 code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

WINDOW_SIZE = '1280,720'

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--window-size=%s' % WINDOW_SIZE)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/pi/.mozilla/firefox/kvz2n0sv.default-esr'), options=options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')

driver.get('url')

# Do stuff

driver.quit()
```

When I run this (both with the profile open and closed), I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/local/bin/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

The full output (including some irrelevant stuff) is:

```
enrichment.py:26: DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please use an Options object
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/pi/.mozilla/firefox/kvz2n0sv.default-esr'), executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver', options=options)
enrichment.py:26: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/pi/.mozilla/firefox/kvz2n0sv.default-esr'), executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver', options=options)
enrichment.py:26: DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/pi/.mozilla/firefox/kvz2n0sv.default-esr'), executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver', options=options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "enrichment.py", line 26, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/pi/.mozilla/firefox/kvz2n0sv.default-esr'), executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver', options=options)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 112, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/local/bin/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own **geckodriver** and use it with **firefox97.0**.
but a simpler way is to install the corresponding file directly using the following command

```
sudo apt install firefox=97.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
sudo apt install firefox-geckodriver=97.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
```

Before installing, I think you should clean up the Firefox and geckodriver installed before.

Then you can use it like this

```
from selenium import webdriver

WINDOW_SIZE = '1280,720'

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--window-size=%s' % WINDOW_SIZE)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get('url')

driver.close()
```

It works on my raspberrypi4B Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS